JavaScript Weather Widget is being invoked twice despite seeing only one function call in the console
My JavaScript Weather Widget is fetching live weather warnings via the Met Office website's RSS feed. The problem is that the warnings display twice on the page, so I think there must be duplicate call to the fetch function that I can't find. The weather-widget.js script is only included once on the page. I have run a stack trace and the console shows only one call, so I can't work out why the warning is being displayed twice. I am using axios for the http request and Bootstrap 5 to display the warnings.
HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Weather Widget</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container mt-5">
        <div class="card shadow-lg">
            <div class="card-header bg-primary text-white">
                <h5 class="mb-0">Weather Warnings</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div id="weather-widget">
                    <p>Loading weather warnings...</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="weather-widget.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


weather-widget.js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    const widgetContainer = document.getElementById("weather-widget");
    const rssFeedUrl = "https://corsproxy.io/https://www.metoffice.gov.uk/public/data/PWSCache/WarningsRSS/Region/yh";

    // Fetch and parse the RSS feed
    async function fetchWeatherWarnings() {
        console.trace("fetchWeatherWarnings() trace");
        try {
            const response = await axios.get(rssFeedUrl, {
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/rss+xml'
                }
            });

            const parser = new DOMParser();
            const xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(response.data, "application/xml");

            // Extract warning items
            const items = xmlDoc.querySelectorAll("item");
            if (items.length === 0) {
                widgetContainer.innerHTML = "<p>No weather warnings available at the moment.</p>";
                return;
            }

            // Generate HTML for warnings
            let warningsHtml = "";
            items.forEach((item) => {
                const title = item.querySelector("title").textContent;
                const link = item.querySelector("link").textContent;
                const description = item.querySelector("description").textContent;
                const enclosure = item.querySelector("enclosure")?.getAttribute("url");

                warningsHtml += `
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <h6 class="fw-bold">${title}</h6>
                        <p>${description}</p>
                        ${enclosure ? `<img src="${enclosure}" alt="Warning icon" class="img-fluid mb-2">` : ""}
                        <a href="${link}" target="_blank" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                `;
            });

            widgetContainer.innerHTML = warningsHtml;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error fetching weather warnings:", error);
            widgetContainer.innerHTML = "<p>Unable to load weather warnings. Please try again later.</p>";
        }
    }

    // Fetch warnings on load
    fetchWeatherWarnings(console.log("Script executed"));
});



The RSS feed https://www.metoffice.gov.uk/public/data/PWSCache/WarningsRSS/Region/yh already contains two items "Yellow warning of wind affecting Yorkshire & Humber", one for tomorrow and one for the day after. Do you see four warnings or only these two?

@HeikoTheißen I am seeing two. I hadn't noticed that there are two warnings in that particular feed. Mystery solved. Thank you.
